# Can't get route 53 domain to point to Heroku app

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, dns, amazon-route53

I moved a godaddy domain to aws. It is registered in route 53 and I can see the domaincontrol.com name servers that I guess came from godaddy.

I followed along with a heroku tutorial which led me to a step where it says [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53#cname-records):

At this point you’ve established the correct DNS configuration but no requests are using it. In order for Route 53 DNS to become active for your application you need to tell your domain registrar (GoDaddy, DNSimple, NameCheap, 1&1 etc…) to use your hosted zone’s Route 53 nameservers.

Go back to the Hosted Zones list and select your new hosted zone. There is a pre-populated Delegation Set section in the sidebar. These are the nameservers you need to provide your domain registrar for Route 53 to resolve your app domain.

Now, route 53 doesn't have any section called delegation set but I've found docs about the reusable delegation set, can't quite wrap my head around them yet but maybe that is where I need to look. But I don't really understand what to do, I think route 53 is my domain registrar since I transferred the domain over so I feel like this should be easy to figure out with everything on the aws end. Does it matter that my custom domain's name servers are those domaincontrol.com name servers from godaddy? I don't understand exactly how the domain transfer works.

I want this domain to connect to heroku, any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I swear I read this in like 10 places. "Don't modify the name servers on your domain."

Yet I went and added in the 4 name servers from my NS record on my hosted zone and I just left the 2 godaddy records there and immediately this worked.

So glad I tried that, now to see if I can get https working